# Regex for number range starting with an underscore

Tags: regex

I am in need of a regex to drill down a list of URLs in Google Analytics containing the values between `_1` and `_63676`, only starting with an underscore

Included:

```
www.example.com/abc_61712
```

Excluded:

```
www.example.com/abc-7-60_61712
```

I came up with the following regex but it doesn't work.

```
^([\s]?_[^\s]*[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-6][0-3][0-6][0-7][0-6])$
```

Any takers to help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to validate the whole URL and return it or is your exercise here just to validate `_1` to `_63676`?

Comment: What makes the second 'exluded'? To me, it matches the rule.

Comment: @JvdV apologies - only the last bit of the URL including the underscore matters

Comment: @PoulBak - apologies - only URLs that start with an underscore followed by the number range should count. URLs including numbers prior the underscore should not be counted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something but hopefully I covered the range from `_1` to `_63676`:

```
^_(?:[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|6[012]\d{3}|63[0-5]\d\d|636[0-6]\d|6367[0-6])$
```

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/gxa7SV/6)

---

- `^_`  - Start string ancor and literal underscore.
- `(?:` - Open a non-capture group.

  - `[1-5]\d{4}` - Match a digit from 1 to 5 with up to 4 digits, basically covering `_10000` up to `_59999` cases.
  - `|` - Or.
  - `[1-9]\d{0,3}` - match a digit from 1-9 and optionally up to three more digits. Covering `_1` to `_9999`
  - `|` - Or.
  - `6[012]\d{3}` - A six followed by 0-2 and any three digits. Covering `_60000` up to `_62999`.
  - `|` - Or.
  - `63[0-5]\d\d` - Literally 63 followed by 0-5 and any two digits covering: `_63000` to `_63599`.
  - `|` - Or.
  - `636[0-6]\d` - Literally 636 followed by 0-6 and any digit to cover: `_63600` to `_63669`.
  - `|` - Or.
  - `6367[0-6]` - Covering what is left: `_63670` to `_63676`.
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `$` - End string ancor.

Comment: The number is not at the start of the url.

Comment: @PoulBak, I know, but since OP has a check on this specific part of the URL in his own attempt I handled it as though he has somehow seperated that part of the string to be checked through regex. If not, i guess it's a relatively easy edit I guess?

Comment: @JvdV what is the regex when I rather want to validate the entire URL?

Comment: @razkal, I suppose that deserves another question on SO if it's specific enough since there are numerous issues resolved around that problem here on so. I guess a quick search may already help you out quite a bit.